# Angular read a very long list in a json file too slow

Tags: angular, angular13

I have a component which basically reads a big list from a json file and shows it in a list, where you scroll using a scrollbar.
Number of items in the list is around 20000 items.

I call the data from a service:

```
getData(){
    return this.httpClient.get(URL_HERE);
}
```

And then call it into my component:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let biglist of item”>{{ item.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

First, the loading is scroll and then the list scrolling is not very smooth.

Is there a better way to list a very large list for example just load 50 at a time…so when scrolling up or down you get the other 50 loaded?

I just don’t know how to go about this in a way where the loading and showing of the list is quick and smooth.

Comment: You can build one of your own but I think you would better use a tested library like: [ngx-inifinite-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-infinite-scroll)

Comment: Does this library load parts from the data or load all the data and scroll bits of it?

Comment: Mainly, It takes care of the scroll, the data could be either from an array on your component or a request to the server with the filtering parameters. If you prefer to fetch all your 20000 records and then filter it its ok I think. The idea is NOT to load to the DOM all the record at once.

Comment: You could use [virtual scrolling from Angular CDK](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview#virtual-scrolling), it does exactly what you want

Answer (score 0):

I have some workaround, it works but not perfect. I tested it in angular 12.2.
For the list with the different of list that is low, you can do with this:

```
//in CSS:
.container {
  height: 2000px;
}

.number {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid maroon;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: fit-content;
}
```

and in app.component.ts file:

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="500" class="container">
          <ul
            *cdkVirtualFor="let employee of employees" class="number">
            
              <li class="class1">HR. Bukhari no.{{ employee.number }}</li>
              <p class="class2">{{ employee.arab }}</p>
              <h2 class="class3">{{ employee.id }}</h2>
          </ul>
        </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

In the example above, the item has size of 500px, and the container has 2000px. So, it will display 4 items at a time. You can change the value to understand it.
The cons of it, the size is fixed, even you have different size of item.